# PHP best way generate large array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to generate a large array with a incremental key and empty value.

I tried:

```
$array = array();

for($i=1; $i <= 1000000; $i++)
   $array[$i] = '';

print_r($array);
```

thrown exception:

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 131072 bytes)
```

What is the most efficient way?

Comment: Your memory is what is insufficient, not the code, but you could try [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/array_fill).

Comment: Do you have a php-conf.ini file used? If you want to allocate more memory than your current limit you'll have to edit some entries in that.

For the record, nickb is absolutely correct. Your method of filling the array is irrelevant to the error you're getting, which is only saying that what you've made is way too big (not how you've made it).

Comment: Also, why would you want to generate a huge empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the title question, checkout the [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:

```
$a = range(0,9);
print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
)
```

The issue you're having though is that you are running out of memory in php. Try increasing the [memory limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) if you really need an array that big.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler and what it's for:

```
$array = array_fill(1, 1000000, '');
```

This still fails at `2MB` so change `memory_limit` to something higher probably `64MB` at least.

Answer (score 1):

Use [range()](http://php.net/range)

```
$arr = range(1,1000000);
```

But it still won't get around the fact that your memory limit is far too low to contain the size of array you want. There is no way around this. You're trying to dump a swimming pool's worth of water into a tea cup, and wondering why it's spilling everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is more memory efficient than looping:

```
$array = array_fill_keys(range(1,1000000), '');
```

Answer (score 1):

First increase your memory size. Then the most efficient way is to use [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php)

It works with PHP >= 5.3.0

```
$array = new SplFixedArray(1000000);
```

In this way you have an array with NULL values.

Comment: What?  I'm just going by the question.  Index starts at 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to make more memory available to your PHP script you can increase the available memory:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

You can make this change in the relevant `php.ini` config file, or during run-time by using `ini_set` with the `memory_limit` key.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increase your memory for one script only, you can use ini_set();

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

Otherwise, you can increase your memory_limit in php.ini

```
memory_limit = 16M
```